# Django. Необходимо вывести 7 постов за текущую неделю, пустые даты заполнить шаблонной фразой

Tags: python, django

Всем доброго дня!
Изучаю python и django.
Поставил себе задачу, сделать для себя спортивный календарь для занятий, в дальнейшем API и подключение бота телеграмм. Идея простая, на определенные даты создавать тренировки (дата, название, сама тренировка). Выводить на страницу расписание на месяц, неделю.

На данный момент столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Модель:

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='workouts'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Вьюшка:

```
def week(request):
    template = 'workouts/week.html'
    date = datetime.datetime.today()
    week = date.strftime("%V")
    workouts = Workout.objects.filter(date__week=week)
    context = {
        'workouts': workouts,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Шаблон:

```
{% block content %}
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="width: 1000%;">
    {% for workout in workouts %}
    <div style="float: left; width: 180px; margin-left: 5px;">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          {{ workout.date }} <br> {{ workout.date|date:"l" }}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h6 class="card-title">{{ workout.title }}</h6>
          <p class="card-text">{{ workout.text }}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Подробно</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Таким образом я вывожу на страницу занятия на текущую неделю, но я хочу, чтобы выводились и пустые дни. То есть если тренировки 3 (вт, чт, сб) - то получить следующее: 7 колонок на странице, в заголовках дата и день недели, ниже если нет тренировки - то текст -тренировок нет, если есть тренировка - то вывести название и тренировку.

Похоже, что нужно создать шаблон с 7 столбацами с каждым днем недели, но я не понимаю, как вывести данные в эти столбцы. Как проверять, что если в queryset сет есть данные на этот день - то выводим, если нет, то пишем занятий нет.

Наверное можно сравнивать даты в шаблоне и выводить данные, но скорее всего это не правильно.

Подозреваю, что можно во вьюшке каким то образом перебирать дни текущей недели, заполнять пустой день и передавать контекст, но моих знаний не хватает к сожалению.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, будет проще взять 7 queryset'ов на каждый день недели.

```
{% for w in workouts1 %}
    <div class="card">
        ваша тренировка в Пн
    </div>
{% empty %}
    тренировок в Пн нет. Добавить?
{% endfor %}

{% for w in workouts2 %}
    <div class="card">
        ваша тренировка в Вт
    </div>
{% empty %}
    тренировок в Вт нет. Добавить?
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Не совсем понимаю, как вьюшка будет в этом случае выглядеть.

Comment: context = {
     'workouts1': Workout.objects.filter(date__week=week, date__деньнедели=1),
}

Comment: Так и сделал вчера в итоге, теперь проблема в том, что даты нет в заголовке, там где нет объекта тренеровки, но это я решу. Теперь меня волнует другой вопрос, когда я буду делать страничку месяца, там не хочется делать 28-31 кверисет =)

Answer (score 0):

Передавай в шаблон не queryset а подготовленный список или словарь по которому затем будешь итерироваться в шаблоне.

```
def week(request):
    template = 'workouts/week.html'
    date = datetime.datetime.today()
    week = date.strftime("%V")
    workouts = Workout.objects.filter(date__week=week)
    schedule = {
        0: {"title": "Понедельник", "workout":  []},
        1: {"title": "Вторник", "workouts": []},
        2: {"title": "Среда", "workouts": []},
        3: {"title": "Четверг", "workouts": []},
        4: {"title": "Пятница", "workouts": []},
        5: {"title": "Суббота", "workouts": []},
        6: {"title": "Воскресенье", "workouts": []},
    }
    for workout in workouts:
        schedule[workout.date.weekday()]["workouts"].append(workout)
    context = {
        'schedule': schedule,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)

и дальше в шаблоне сначала итерируешься по дням, а затем внутри дня по тренировкам

{% block content %}
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="width: 1000%;">
    {% for day in schedule %}
        {{ day.title }}
        {% for workout in day.workouts %}
        <div style="float: left; width: 180px; margin-left: 5px;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              {{ workout.date }} <br> {{ workout.date|date:"l" }}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">{{ workout.title }}</h6>
              <p class="card-text">{{ workout.text }}</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Подробно</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

В дальнейшем не составит труда переделать отображение недели на отображение месяца

Comment: Андрей, спасибо за ответ!
Но у меня не заработало)

Comment: Внес правки в код, чтобы заработало:
    title = ''
    schedule = {
            0: {title: "Понедельник", workouts: []},    
    }
объявил пустой титл , и в словаре исправил = на : , иначе код не работал.
Но на страничке в браузере получаю ошибку: Exception Type: KeyError, Exception Value: 'workouts'. 
Скорее всего, я не так тебя понял и что то не так исправил)

Comment: и судя по всему, во все 7 дней, записался одинаковый набор данных.

Comment: Исправил определение словаря. Ключи словаря в кавычки и заменил =, на :

Comment: Ошибка ушла, но, к сожалению, страница пустая, данные не выводятся.